# Filling in NaN for a set time range

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with Python to:

1. Looping through my dataset and finding the first non NaN value in column color and storing that Value as Base_color
2. I want to fill all NaN values within a 5 second range after the Base_color with the Base color only if those values are NaN
3. If it picks up a new color within the 5 seconds, I want to store the color as base and replace all NaN after our new found base_color, within a 5 second range with the new found base color

This is an example of my Dataset:

```
 Name Color Emotion  Time
 Bob  NA    angry    2018-11-20 16:14:31

 Bob  NA    angry    2018-11-20 16:14:31

 Bob  red   sad      2018-11-20 16:14:31

 Bob  red   neutral  2018-11-20 16:14:31

 Bob  blue  sad      2018-11-20 16:14:32

 Bob  red   sad      2018-11-20 16:14:32

 Bob  NA    neutral  2018-11-20 16:14:33

 Bob  NA    neutral  2018-11-20 16:14:33

 Bob  NA    sad      2018-11-20 16:14:34

 Bob  blue  fear     2018-11-20 16:14:35
```

Please help :) Thanks

Comment: Please do not share images of code or data, share a sample of your dataframe instead

Comment: Share code so that we can reproduce your data set and help you find your solution.

Comment: @AlexandreNixon I have changed it thanks for the advise

Comment: @MohitMotwani I honestly don't know where to start with writing the code, i know what I have to achieve but I need help with the code

Answer (score 0):

To find the first_valid color use:

```
valid_index = df['Color'].first_valid_index()
base_color = df['Color'][valid_index]
```

For your question 2 & 3:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((row['Time'] - df['Time'][valid_index]).dt.seconds < 5):
        if row['Color'] == np.nan:
            row['Color'] = base_color
        else:
            base_color = row['Color']
            valid_index = index
```